# Cant log in to Mysql

Tags: linux, mysql

When I try to log in to  mysql using `mysql -u root -p` it gives me this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have looked in the directory and the file isn't there. I have looked around and people have said that sqld has to be running but I don't know how to start it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/etc/init.d/mysql start`, or if it has a different name than `mysql`, look for something that looks like it applies.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this should start your MySQL server:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Depending on which Linux distro you use, the command might be different.

Comment: i get this `/etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory` when i enter that in. I also used service mysqld and that doesn't work. I am running Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Have you installed MySQL server, even? `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` — it should start automatically after the installation is complete.